# WSO2 Enterprise Store 1.0.0: security

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-es

In **WSO2 Enterprise Store 1.0.0** there is a lack of security on some aspects.

For example: several **public files** contain **sensitive data** as the location and clear password of keystores:

- **/store/config/publisher.json**
- **/publisher/config/publisher.json**

I'm still trying to figure why these data are needed on client side...

Is there any **configuration setting** to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by adding following URL mapping to the jaggery.conf inside both publisher and store apps.

```
{
 "url": "/config/*",
 "path": "/"
}
```

Comment: Should not be the default setting?

Comment: yes, you can find the commit here https://github.com/wso2/enterprise-store/commit/e068416c0a5bec252ac5d949187a685096794eab